# Using Multiple Storyboards with Tab Bar Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard

I'm trying to get my application to load up a different storyboard depending on the device that it is running on. Right now, I have been able to detect the device and set the rootViewController in the AppDelegate based on it. I've noticed, however, that when I do this, my Tab Bar Controller disappears. I think this is happening because I am simply setting the rootViewController as a new instance. How would I fix this problem so that the Tab Bar will be visible?

AppDelegate.swift

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    window =  UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()


    if ((UIDevice.currentDevice().modelName == "iPhone 5") || (UIDevice.currentDevice().modelName == "iPhone 5c") || (UIDevice.currentDevice().modelName == "iPhone 5s") || (UIDevice.currentDevice().modelName == "iPhone SE") || (UIDevice.currentDevice().modelName == "iPod Touch 5") || (UIDevice.currentDevice().modelName == "iPod Touch 6")) {

        storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "iPhoneSE", bundle: nil)
        let rootController = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("login5")

        if let window = self.window {
            window.rootViewController = rootController
        }

        print("-----------------------iPhone5-----------------------")

    } else if ((UIDevice.currentDevice().modelName == "iPhone 6") || (UIDevice.currentDevice().modelName == "iPhone 6s")){

        storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "iPhone6", bundle: nil)
        let rootController = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("login6")

        if let window = self.window {
            window.rootViewController = rootController
        }

        print("-----------------------iPhone6-----------------------")

    }
```

Comment: Why do you have separate storyboards? That goes against everything you should be doing? And it doesn't scale.

Comment: I would recommend reading up on constraints... You might find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ios/792/auto-layout#t=201608191742048675405

Answer (score 1):

Just a real stupid idea:  You are making the window visible before you instantiate the relevant StoryBoard.    Try moving the makeKeyAndVisible() line after the conditionals.

Comment: That didn't seem to work. The tab bar is still not visible.